# Best method to redirect user fom callback

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, callback

We load an iframe, of which the contents are controlled by a third-party provider. The user performs the required actions. Could take 1 minute to 15 minutes. Once the actions are complete the third-party provider sends a message to our callback alerting us. Currently here is how we solve:

```
function getStatus() {
    var action = "getStatus";
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/scripts/scripts.php",
        data: { "action" : action, "id" : id },
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function( html ) {
            if ( html == "Success" )
                window.location.href = "/next-step";
            else
                return setTimeout( getStatus, 2000 );
        }
    } );
}

getStatus();
```

When we get a callback, we update the database noting the action is complete. Mean while, we use jquery to query the database every 2 seconds looking for a completion and when that occurs, we redirect user.

Querying the database looking for a success seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is the problem with http where the client needs to poll the data from backend to check for an update that happened.

A better solution will be the use of websocket which will allow the backend to notify the frontend when a change has occurred.

[Here is the link to websocket](https://www.websocket.org/)

It is relatively easy to set up and use.